# Ping a virtualbox machine from the host machine shows "Destination Host Unreachable"

Tags: linux, networking, interface, virtualbox, adapter

I don't know why but I can't ping a virtual machine node from the host. I have created a network:
*vboxnet1*:

```
IPv4 Address: 192.168.57.0
IPv4 Network Mask: 255.255.255.0
IPv6 Address: fe80:0000:0000:0000:0800:27ff:fe00:0000
IPv6 Network Mask Length: 64
```

Then I have created a virtual machine with 2 interfaces:
adapter 1: NAT
adapter 2: Host-only Adapter. Name: vboxnet1

Check "Cable Connected"

Then I have Installed CentOS 7 on VM.

edit: */etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0*:

```
DEVICE=eth0
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
DEFROUTE=yes
ONBOOT=yes
```

edit: */etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1*:

```
TYPE=Ethernet
IPADDR=192.168.57.111
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
BOOTPROTO=static
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_PEERDNS=yes
IPV6_PEERROUTES=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
NAME=eth1
DEVICE=eth1
ONBOOT=yes
```

"ip addr" on VM shows that eth0 is 10.0.2.15/24 and eth1 is 192.168.57.111/24

"route -n" on host machine shows:

```
0.0.0.0 192.168.0.1 0.0.0.0 UG 0 0 0 wlan0
192.168.0.0 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.0 U 0 0 0 wlan0
192.168.56.0 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.0 U 0 0 0 vboxnet0
192.168.57.0. 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.0 U 0 0 0 vboxnet1
```

Virtual machines can ping each other. Also, Virtual machines can ping the host machine but the host machine can't ping virtual machines.

Can somebody explain why it isn't working?

Comment: I have this same issue with my VM (also RHEL), and bridged networking is not a solution - I need the VM to work when the host has no "outside" network connection, and I need the VM to have a fixed IP address, so that the host can connect to the database running on the host. Is there really no solution for host-only networking?

Comment: That message means the host MAC address is not in the ARP table and the host did not answer an ARP request in the time allotted.

Answer (score -1):

I used a bridge network because security isn't a concern in my setup.

Here is a summary of tutorial in the link from @ser99.sh

Select the virtual machine that you want to connect to your network:
[image: virtual box manager]

Rightclick your virtual machine and select `settings --> network settings --> bridge network`:
[image]

Start up your virtual machine and select a suitable static IP address:
[image]

Verify that you have access to other computers:
[image: virtual machine setup]

Comment: Downvote because the question is about host-only network. This answer does not clarify the original issue at all.

Answer (score -3):

If you want connect your host machine with guest machines, you can use "bridge network"

http://www.thegeeky.space/2015/06/how-to-set-and-run-bridge-virtual-network-on-CentOS-Kali-Linux-Windows-in-Virtualbox-with-practical-example.html

Comment: Please fix your image

Comment: Answers that are just links are bad. The link might eventually die.

Comment: Bridge network will show your virtualbox machine to outside network (security concerns). Also, you will lose the connection with your virtualbox machine when your interface losses connection with external network (wi-fi or anything else). Also, if you are not using home network but public network, it isn't always easy to connect to the public network from your virtualbox machine. Bridge network should be used only when you want your VBox machine to be accessed outside from your home machine.